# why promise not work properly then function not fired?

Tags: javascript, jquery

could you please tell me why `then` function not call ?I try to fetch `json` data from `file`
here is my code
https://plnkr.co/edit/3APaLWC7QkNuvxHirL14?p=preview

```
function abc(){
  return check();
}
function check(){
   return  $.ajax({
            url:'data.json',
            success: function (json) {
              return json;
            }
        })
}
$(function(){
  abc().then(function(d){
    console.log(d)
  })
})
```

Comment: Why you think `.then()` (or it's callback) isn't executed? The script works (@MichalPerlakowski) and the content of `data.json` is printed in the console

Comment: @Andreas Trying to do `return json;` in a callback function clearly shows that the OP has no idea how asynchronous functions work.